# Foreign key relationship; how to save in Post - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys, django-views

I am trying to relate the creation of an entry and make this the foreign of another model within a post. I tried to do this at first with a signal but thought it might be easier creating the relationship during the POST:

Code:

```
if request.POST:
    if formWG.is_valid(): 

    instance =formWG.save(commit=False)

    about = formWG.cleaned_data.get("about")
    country = formWG.cleaned_data.get("country")
    state = formWG.cleaned_data.get("state")
    city = formWG.cleaned_data.get("city")

    #instance.user = request.user
    instance.about = about
    instance.country = country
    instance.state = state
    instance.city = city
    instance.admins = [request.user.id]

    instance.save()

    groupMembers.objects.create(members = [request.user] ,createdGroupFK_id = instance.id)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('groups2:index'))

return render(request, "groups2/creategroup.html", context)
```

My members column is an Int Array type, hence I set it to " [request.user]"

The Models.py is:

```
class groupCreateAndAdminAccess(models.Model):

    workGroupName = models.CharField(max_length = 80, unique=True)
    about  = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    interests = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True))
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)

    admins =  ArrayField(models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True),
              blank=True, null=True)


class groupMembers(models.Model):

    createdGroupFK =  models.ForeignKey(
        'groupCreateAndAdminAccess',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    members = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True),
              blank=True, null=True)
```

If anyone in the community could help or point to resources. I just need to know how to get the creation of the group within the groups table to relate itself via a foreign key to the Group members table within the POST. Or if there are much better alternatives.

Comment: Please post the code for the relevant models.

Comment: hi, i added it above thanks

Comment: What is your issue? I.e is there an error you see? Also, is the [ArrayField the PostgreSQL specific field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)? Why not use [a ManyToMany field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)?